# Using Hilt but the base project is using Dagger

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I want to use `Hilt` with the `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation in `MyActivity`, but I have to create classes by extending `BaseActivity`  from a first-party library, which appears to use a different dependency injection tool. (`Dagger`, I reckon)

MyActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint // if I do not use Hilt, there is no error.
class MyActivity : BaseActivity() { 
   @Inject
   lateinit var something: Something
}
```

BaseActivity.java

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Inject
   protected Logger log; // this causes the error.
}
```

I have got an error like

```
/package/HiltComponents error:[Dagger/MissingBinding] *Logger* cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method
```

```
Missing binding usage: *Logger* is injected at ... MyActivity is injected at injectMyActivity ...
```

Is it possible to use `Dagger` and `Hilt` together in this way?

FYI, I have no auth to access the first-library code.

Comment: You'd need to include all the manually tied together Dagger components into the same graph.

Comment: Hilt is an advanced version of dagger you just need to define all dependencies in a file with `@Provides`  and `@Singleton` annotation in Module Class with `@Module` Annotation.

Comment: @GabeSechan Hmm I have never tried Dagger but should I instanciate all components from the base class? I heard Hilt supports bytecode transformation whereas Dagger's not.

Comment: Hilt is built on top of Dagger.